# C list sorting program works only after debugging

Tags: c, list, debugging, sorting, structure

I wrote a little program that reads words from txt file and puts them in a list; then, it sorts the words and puts them back in the file. When I run the program, it freezes, but when I debug it, it works perfectly. How do I fix this?

Here's my code. Reading from the file to the list and writing back to the file works well (checked on other programs). I didn't know how to sort the list alphabetically so I'm using arrays:

```
typedef struct bazaslowek                                    
{
    char *word;
    struct bazaslowek* next;
} baza;

void SORTING (baza **head)
{//================================file->list, works good
    char word[30];
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("bazaslow.txt", "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening txt file!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s\n", word);
            baza *wsk = *head;
            baza *new = malloc (sizeof(baza));
            new -> next = NULL;
            new -> word = strdup(word);
            if(wsk == NULL)
            {
                new -> next = *head;
                *head = new;
            }
            else
            {
                while(wsk -> next != NULL)
                    wsk = wsk -> next;
                wsk -> next = new;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //==========================================Here's the sorting, problem is probably here

    baza *wsk= (*head);
    char tab1[31], tab2[31];
    if(wsk ->next != NULL)
        while(wsk->next != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(tab1, wsk->word, 30);
            memcpy(tab2, wsk->next->word, 30);
            if (strcmp(tab1, tab2) > 0)
            {
                memcpy(wsk->word, tab2, 30);
                memcpy(wsk->next->word, tab1, 30);
            }
            wsk = wsk->next;
        }

    //======================list->file, works good
    if ((fp = fopen("bazaslow.txt", "w"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening file!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        baza *wsk = *head;
        while (wsk != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", wsk->word);
            wsk=wsk->next;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    baza *head=NULL;
    printf("Sorting time!\n");
    SORTING(&head);
    return 0;
}
```

I really have no idea why it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. I'm sitting on it for a longer while but can't change the code so it will work always. Could anyone help me please? What is wrong? How should the code look so the program will always work?

Comment: What happens when you run the debug build *not* in the debugger? And what happens if you debug the release build (this is more difficult to do because the debugger won't know all values)?

Comment: I recommend proper indentation, it really helps to understand the code better

Comment: noelicus, how do I do that? I'm not from English-speaking country and have a little problem understanding what do you mean. If you could tell me how to do it, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: `memcpy(wsk->word, tab2, 30);` `wsk->word` is not necessarily the size of 30. You should only need to replace the pointer simply.

Comment: I was trying to do this with replacing pointers, but it doesn't work for me, probably make some mistakes. How should I do this?

Comment: i post answer(sample). also There is a potential problem with  `while(!feof(fp))`, change to `while(EOF!=fscanf(fp,"%s\n", word))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g sort sample

```
baza *outerp, *innerp;
for(outerp=*head;outerp->next != NULL;outerp=outerp->next){
    for(innerp = outerp->next;innerp != NULL;innerp=innerp->next){
        if(strcmp(outerp->word, innerp->word) > 0){
            char *tmp = outerp->word;
            outerp->word = innerp->word;
            innerp->word = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```